# Efficient way in sending data from nodejs server to client using socketio

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to create a simple chat app using nodejs, express, socketio and mysql. My question is, what is the most efficient way to send chat history data that I queried from mysql database in my nodejs server to the newly connected client application? Should I send the query results all at once and do the loop in client side or do the loop in nodejs server and send query results one by one to the client?

Comment: Please try something and ask questions when you have a real code problem. In general *"best"* can be subjective and app dependent

Answer (score 1):

If by "efficient", you mean the least bandwidth to send the data, then it's nearly always more efficient to send one larger chunk of data then it is to send lots of smaller pieces of data (because there's overhead involved in each transmission).  You could just send a JSON-encoded array where each item in the array is a step in the history.  There are, of course, limits where you might want to break up really large pieces of data into more manageable pieces, so if your total data was hundreds of MBs, you probably don't want to send all of that at once.  But, if the total chat history is smaller than tens of MBs, probably best to just send it all at once (if your goal is to send it all).

Depending upon what you're sending, a plain JSON array of objects with lots of repeated property names is not always the most efficient format to send though it's always worth an experiment or two with compression turned on to see if it makes any difference or not.  We can't really comment further on that without seeing exactly what data you are sending.

In the future, you will get much more meaningful answers if you ask a specific question about your specific code and show both the code and the data you are sending.  Then, we can target our answer to your specific situation rather than having to make guesses about what your situation might be.  Theoretical questions pretty much never work as well here as specific questions about your actual code/data.  For some reason, there appears to be an instinct to ask a generic form of the question without your actual code/data, but that is usually exactly the wrong way to go and is a ton harder to offer a meaningful and specific answer to.

Comment: @ezekiel - Did this answer your question?